# Click all buttons with svg class

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I would like to click all buttons on a page under this class

```
<svg class="opinionate-action post-agree" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 14.7 18.4" data-reactid=".0.2.1.0.2.0.$57047af48bd3ef3c0ddf7dd8.$57047af48bd3ef3c0ddf7dd8.0.1.5.1.0.0.0" style="-webkit-user-select: auto;"><g data-reactid=".0.2.1.0.2.0.$57047af48bd3ef3c0ddf7dd8.$57047af48bd3ef3c0ddf7dd8.0.1.5.1.0.0.0.0" style="-webkit-user-select: auto;"><path d="M14.4,12.3c0.2-0.4,0.3-0.9,0.3-1.4c0-0.7-0.3-1.4-0.7-2c0-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.4c0-1.7-1.3-3.2-3-3.3 c0-0.3,0.1-0.7,0.1-1.1c0-2.3-1.7-4-4.1-4c-0.3,0-0.4,0-0.4,0L4.8,0.4v2.9C4.4,4.2,3.5,4.9,3,5.1l0,0C1.3,5.9, 0.1,7.8,0.1,9.9v3.3 v0.1c0,2.8,2.3,5.2,5.2,5.2h5.3c1.8,0,3.2-1.3,3.2-3c0-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.2c0.5-0.5,0.8-1.2, 0.8-2C14.6,12.9,14.5,12.6,14.4,12.3z M12.6,13.2c0,0.6-0.6,1-1.2,1h-0.5c0.4,0.1,1,0.7,1,1.2c0,0.6-0.6,1-1.2, 1H5.3c-1.7,0-3.2-1.4-3.2-3.2V9.9c0-1.2,0.7-2.5,1.8-3 c0.8-0.6,2.5-1.5,2.9-3.4V2.2c0,0,2.4-0.3,2.4,2c0, 2.6-1.6,3-0.3,3.1h2c0.7,0,1.3,0.7,1.3,1.4c0,0.6-0.6,1-1,1.1h0.5 c0.6,0,1.2,0.6,1.2,1.3c0,0.6-0.6,1-1.2, 1h0C12,12.1,12.6,12.6,12.6,13.2z" data-reactid=".0.2.1.0.2.0.$57047af48bd3ef3c0ddf7dd8.$57047af48bd3ef3c0ddf7dd8.0.1.5.1.0.0.0.0.0" style="-webkit-user-select: auto;"></path></g></svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this with jQuery :

```
$(function(){
    $('.opinionate-action.post-agree').on('click',function(e){
    console.log('click !');
    // the code you want to execute here
    });
})
```

Bonne soirée !
Frédéric

Comment: Just got a #document return, no action on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to actually click all the buttons and not set click handler. Not sure what will be the real world use case for that but try this instead with jQuery.

```
$(function(){
    $('.opinionate-action.post-agree').click();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **$('document').ready** to load full page and after click buttons, because without it you click elements what not loaded yet (this mean that you click nothing)

```
  $('document').ready(function f(){
  $('.opinionate-action.post-agree').click();
  });
```

Or if is need to exclude some elements

```
  $('.opinionate-action.post-agree').each(function () {if($(this).attr('some_attr')!='1') $(this).click();} );
```

**OR WHY NOT USE JS ONLY**

```
 var a= document.getElementsByClassName('opinionate-action');

 var a= document.querySelectorAll('[class^=opinionate-action]');

 var a= getElementsByAttribute('data-reactid');

 for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
 { 
 a[i].click();
 console.log(a[i]);
 }
```

Comment: To use native JS attributes like `getElementsByClassName` or `querySelectorAll`, you need to iterate over them, as they return a NodeList or HTMLCollection.

Comment: @litel and you see a problem in iterating nodes or collections? jQuery also iterate it I think